# groupby with multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df  fruit  year sale  important
0   apple  2010  
1   apple  2011
2   apple  2012
3   apple  2013
4   apple  2014 True    Yes
5   apple  2015 True
6   apple  2017 True
7   apple  2018 True
7   apple  2019 
8   apple  2020 True    Yes
9   banana 2010
...
```

How could I generate the "important" column?

It's Yes if per fruit:
(1) There is a sale that year and
(2) there was no sale the year before and
(3) there is at least a 3-year gap between that year and the previous "important" year.

Comment: can you provide the data as a dictionary

Comment: I tried df.to_dict() but that didn't seem to work properly

Comment: @asd Are all the years present sequentially for each `fruit`?

Comment: Yes the df is sorted by fruit and year (i.e from the old to most recent year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try if this works for your case. Assuming that df is sorted by fruit and year.

```
for i in df['fruit'].unique():
    df1 = df[(df['sale'] == 'True') & (df['sale'].shift() != 'True') & (df['fruit'] == i)]
    df1 = df1[(df1['year'].diff() >=3) | (df1['year'].diff().fillna(0) == 0)]
    df.loc[df.index.isin(df1.index), 'important'] = 'Yes'
```

Prints:

```
    fruit   year    sale    important
0   apple   2010    None    NaN
1   apple   2011    None    NaN
2   apple   2012    None    NaN
3   apple   2013    None    NaN
4   apple   2014    True    Yes
5   apple   2015    True    NaN
6   apple   2017    True    NaN
7   apple   2018    True    NaN
8   apple   2019    None    NaN
9   apple   2020    True    Yes
10  banana  2010    True    NaN
```

I tested with few random combination of fruits and years and was working as far as I could check.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how```df.index.isin(df1.index) ``` works?

Comment: Sure. df1 contains all the elements which matches all the three conditions. Now to tie back the df1 to the original df. I am matching df and df1's index using the `isin` command and calling out a new column named 'important' as 'yes for those matches that returns True.

Comment: I had to use this, `df1['year'].diff().fillna(0) == 0` because, the first difference always returns diff of NaN because there is no previous true value for it to compare.For e.g `apple  2014 True` in your example has no previous 'important' year for it to compare, so the `.diff()` on it will return as NaN which I am converting to Zero and including by default by using `df1['year'].diff().fillna(0) == 0`